# How to get the hostname with CMake or CTest

Tags: cmake, ctest

is it possible to easily get the hostname on which the CMake configuration is launched ?

If it is not possible, how can I get the hostname on which CTest is launched ?

I am using CMake and CTest under Windows and Linux.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CMake site_name() function should give you what you want. To get info on it do "cmake --help-command SITE_NAME".